# Opening a simple OleDB connection throws OutOfMemory Exception?

Tags: .net, windows, ms-access, oledb, out-of-memory

I am having troubles with one of our applications. It's .NET 3.5 32 bits process. Upon startup we open a .mdb to read a few "metadata" values. This works on hundreds of systems, but we have a customer with a TabletPC and problems. The operating system is Windows XP Tablet PC SP3, 32 bits, bla bla. Nothing unusual. It has .NET 3.5 (from Windows Update) All up to date. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Since our application does a "few things" during startup, I've created the simplest console application ever:

```
namespace TestAccessConnection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            OleDbConnection connection;
           try
            {
                connection =
                    new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=metadata.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
                connection.Open();
                connection.Close();
                Console.Read();
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

If we execute that single .exe without the file "metadata.mdb" in the same path, we get the obvious: "file not found bla bla bla". That is correct.

If we copy the metadata (*more on metadata later*), we get this:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' has occurred.
  at System.Data.Common.ADP.IsSysTxEqualSysEsTransaction()
  at System.Data.Common.ADP.NeedManualEnlistment()
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
  at TestAccessConnection.Program.Main(String[] args
```

*note: the exception was in spanish and I translated it, but the content remains the same, the only differences were the "an exception of type", but the Namespaces are untouched*

**What's in the metadata?**:
It's a simple MS ACCESS 2000 file with one table and a couple of records (it stores different MS-SQL connection strings in an encrypted form), so upon startup we can read the connections, decrypt them and present a list for the user to choose different connections. 
None of that functionality is present (or executed) in the test program I've created, since the exception is thrown (apparently) in the connection.Open()

**More about this computer in particular**
The box seems normal. We've reinstalled .NET from different sources (Windows Update) and the dotnetfx.exe (the big 250mb file) and even executed a "repair" from that big .net installer.
.NET seems to work, since this little console application targets .NET 3.5.

**Why this test?**
The reason why the console application does only that it's because our own application does (Among a few other things) that as soon as it starts executing Main(), it's one of the first things we do, so I isolated that piece of code and found out that the exception is being thrown there. In order to make sure that none of our code had anything to do, I created the test application and found the weird exception.

**What about Google?**
I have been frantically searching google/SO/etc. to no avail. OutOfMemory is a very misleading search term, even when coupled with oledb and other "possible" keywords ('tho I might be missing something). Trying to search using other parts of the namespaces, points to  weird results that do not appear to be related to this particular issue.

**What is the question?**
Oh, that's simple: Any Ideas?

**Catch**
I am trying to avoid reinstalling the whole Windows (which might as well fix the problem, given that this simple thing works on hundreds of other computers). The box doesn't appear to be infected with malware or similar, it's a Tablet PC used in Healthcare, so the Internet access although "open" is rarely used if used at all.
This doesn't mean the box is 100% clean (you can never be sure with Windows). 
If you know or have experienced this issue (and found a fix), please enlighten me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While I'm all for people using Jet/ACE as a data store in a number of programming environments, isn't it overkill for the user you're making? Why not an XML file instead? For such a small amount of data wouldn't that be a lot easier?

Comment: Yes, although you must consider the fact that this was created almost six years ago. A small .mdb was an easy and practical way to store a simple table. Maybe it's time to replace it (specially now that we know that there will not be JET64 bits). ;)

Comment: Have you tried the connection to other oledb data sources? another msaccess file? the same file with another name? I know my question can sound stupid, but your problem is quite surprising . If nothing appears, I would then follow DWF's advice and go for a XML file as another way to store the data.

Comment: I haven't tried connecting to other data sources, the msaccess file has been changed (ie. copied from other working systems). I haven't renamed it tho, never thought of that given that it has been working for more than five years under than name. Apparently a "computer tech" is going to reinstall the box because when he tried to repair .NET 3.5 he got some errors. I haven o physical access to the box at the moment. I will, anyway, consider XML as a viable option for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been dead for over a year now, and I've since ported the code to use a single small XML file. We haven't had any problems since then.

Basically the app starts and if it doesn't detect the XML, it looks for the MDB, if it finds it, it tries to open it (always catching for possible errors), if it can open it, it reads the contents and creates the XML, saves it and closes the MDB forever :)

It has worked with more than 1000 machines so far, however the cause of the memory error is still unknown.